# How to print Chinese and Korean character in PDF using Zend_Pdf?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-pdf

I tried to print text in pdf in Chinese and Korean characters using the Zend_Pdf library, but it seems its not showed on the pdf slide.I'm just wondering if Zend_Pdf supports chinese and korean language. I already searched on google but i dont find a solution on that so that's why I ask my question here and need help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The following example is how to use Zend_Mail in Japanese. This is one of CJK (aka CJKV ) languages. **If you use Chinese, you may use HZ-GB-2312 instead of ISO-2022-JP.**

you can follow same process for Zend_pdf to pass character to print in pdf

```
function myConvert($string) {
    return mb_convert_encoding($string, 'ISO-2022-JP', 'UTF-8');
}

$mail = new Zend_Mail('ISO-2022-JP');
// In this case, you can use ENCODING_7BIT
// because the ISO-2022-JP does not use MSB.
$mail->setBodyText(
    myConvert('This is the text of the mail.'),
    null,
    Zend_Mime::ENCODING_7BIT
);
$mail->setHeaderEncoding(Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64);
$mail->setFrom('somebody@example.com', myConvert('Some Sender'));
$mail->addTo('somebody_else@example.com', myConvert('Some Recipient'));
$mail->setSubject(myConvert('TestSubject'));
$mail->send();
```

**EDIT**

```
$page->drawText('Janko Hraško', 200, 643, 'HZ-GB-2312');
```

Also refer

http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-588

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.pdf.drawing.html

hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Hi @liyakat,
  Thank you for your solution. I tried it and it seems it doesn't work. :(

Comment: already tried that. but not working again. im not sure if zend_pdf supports chinese character..

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution by using.

```
$font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath('ChineseOrKorean.ttf',Zend_Pdf_Font::EMBED_DONT_COMPRESS  );
```